# Error when trying to install react-redux dependency

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux

I am getting an error trying to install the react-redux package onto my create-react-app application. I have tried deleting and reinstalling my node_modules folder as well as installing it with admin permissions and I am still receiving the same error

```
➜  frontend git:(main) ✗ npm i react-redux
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
```

Here is the remaining output from the console

```
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.3" from react-redux@7.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!   react-redux@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Here is the list of current dependencies in my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tachyons": "^4.12.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

It looks like you are using the latest npm version (v7).
As mention in the logs, try with
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

---

The last time npm Blog mentioned the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag was while their beta version of npm v7 got public. To read more about the flag go [here](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major).

Comment: Trying install another npm package and got similar errors. Installing with option `--legacy-peer-deps` solved the issues.

Answer (score 17):

Two ways:

1. `npm install <package-name> --legacy-peer-deps`
2. install Recommended node version for most users

The better way is to install the recommended version of node to work for all packages.

Comment: I tried to use the recommended version of node, still has the error

Answer (score 14):

Try installing recommended nodejs version(screen shot below). Which should fix this issue.

[image]

Here is a recreation of this error and its solution (screenshots below):

**Problem:**

**Nodejs : Latest features:**

[image]

**Solution:**

**Nodejs : Recommended for most users:**

[image]

Installing the Recommended version of node js fixed this issue instantly allowing installation of relevant dependancies.

*Incase you are facing this issue with a react-native dependency then once you have installed the recommended version be sure to update your pod file.*

Comment: what is the pod file?

Comment: @KamranAsgari pod file is in ios development where the packages are installed.

Answer (score 4):

Try using Node.js latest "Recommended For Most Users" Version .
it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and nothing seemed to work.
I fixed it by `downgrading node to version 12.14.1`
Uninstall the current node version and install 12.14.1 from [this](https://www.npackd.org/p/org.nodejs.NodeJS64/12.14.1) link

Comment: Or you can use the official node.js downloads at `https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/`. For me, 12.14.1 was too old, I had to use 12.22.5 for MacOS to be happy with it.

Comment: Thanks FROM node:12.14.1-alpine it work

Answer (score 2):

Tried for Mac, it worked.. follow the steps for upgrading to the latest LTS

1. Before updating the Node.js release, check which version you are currently using with:
   node -v
2. Next, clear npm cache with the command:
   npm cache clean -f
3. Install n globally:
   npm install -g n
4. Now that you have n installed, you can use the module to install the latest stable release of Node.js:
   sudo n stable

Alternatively, you can install the Node.js release with the latest features:

sudo n latest

Or, install a specific version number with:
n [version.number]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, so id run this command
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

Then  I simply created my react app using redux template by following

npx create-react-app app-name --template redux

worked for me!!

Answer (score -1):

Its a little bit late but you can resolve this with `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` options. Either should work as mentioned in the error reported by `npm`

Answer (score -3):

Try adding it with yarn. Worked for me

Comment: Thank you, worked for me after installing yarn via `npm install -g yarn`