# Not able to install reactstrap

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

> In case of installing react-icons, reactstrap and react-toastify

```
C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\Desktop\React20\four-tictactoe>npm install react-icons reactstrap  react-toastify
npm ERR!  code ERESOLVE
npm ERR!  ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!  Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR!  node_modules/react
npm ERR!  peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm ERR!  node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!  @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!  peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR!  node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!  peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm ERR!  node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!  @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!  react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!  2 more (reactstrap, react-transition-group)
npm ERR!  5 more (the root project, react-icons, react-toastify, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!  Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR!  peer react@"0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-popper@1.3.7
npm ERR!  node_modules/reactstrap/node_modules/react-popper
npm ERR!  react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.8.0
npm ERR!  node_modules/reactstrap
npm ERR!  reactstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!  Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR!  this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR!  to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!  See C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR!  A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!  C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-25T16_47_42_992Z-debug.log
```

> In case of using --force

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm WARN node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm WARN @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project       
npm WARN 6 more (react-dom, the root project, react-icons, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-popper@1.3.7
npm WARN node_modules/reactstrap/node_modules/react-popper
npm WARN react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.8.0
npm WARN node_modules/reactstrap
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm WARN node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm WARN @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project       
npm WARN 6 more (react-dom, the root project, react-icons, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-popper@1.3.7
npm WARN node_modules/reactstrap/node_modules/react-popper
npm WARN react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.8.0
npm WARN node_modules/reactstrap
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR! @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR! peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR! @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 2 more (reactstrap, react-transition-group)
npm ERR! 5 more (the root project, react-icons, react-toastify, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from create-react-context@0.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/reactstrap/node_modules/create-react-context
npm ERR! create-react-context@"^0.3.0" from react-popper@1.3.7
npm ERR! node_modules/reactstrap/node_modules/react-popper
npm ERR! react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/reactstrap
npm ERR! reactstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Anupam K Krishnan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-25T17_16_41_640Z-debug.log
```

### Also tried adding an .env file with SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
even this doesn't work

---

**All this error is coming while installing reactstrap**
**What I've tried**
1)Deleted node modules and package-lock.json
2)updated npm
3)reinstalled npm

**Even I tried --force but nothing happend**

**Still error is there**

Comment: post your error, instead of images, and what is the error when installing reactstrap, can you post that individually

Comment: what is the error you are getting when you try this `npm i -S reactstrap`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64539759/13126651 try this

Comment: @Anupam Kumar Krishnan Rather than leaving an error as a comment, it would be better to edit and paste your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:**

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "babel-eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
   This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if C:\Users\asus\Desktop\react20\node_modules\babel-eslint is outside your project directory.
   For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls babel-eslint in your project folder.
   This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

**If nothing works then run Command :**

> npm install reactstrap --legacy-peer-deps

To overcome this problem run the above command that overcome that problem